# How to set items spacing in a horizontal menu?

Tags: asp.net, menu

Horizontal menu items:

```
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Registration" Value="Registration"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Log In" Value="Log In"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="About Us" Value="About Us"></asp:MenuItem>
```

Problem: space between items is the same as the space between words in an item (Log In, About Us).
I'm looking for a property named "itemspace" or something like that, but, it seems there is no such one.
Or, maybe, there is?

Comment: A related question was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822122/how-do-i-add-space-between-items-in-an-asp-net-radiobuttonlist

Comment: this question is about radio buttons, not about menu items. It doesn't work with menu items, and does work with radio buttons.

Answer (score 13):

```
<staticmenuitemstyle horizontalpadding="10"/>
```

Comment: I tried this and Gary's solution, but it wasn't working for me in Chrome. I already had the menu directly underneath a div with id="content", so I just did this in external css: `#content > table {border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2px}`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I have used this approach:

```
<StaticMenuItemStyle ItemSpacing="10px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add border width as an alternative

```
<staticmenuitemstyle BorderWidth="20px" BackColor="Green" BorderColor="#ededed" forecolor="Black"/>
```