# how to add space between radiobuttonlist which is created dynamically in code behind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, radio-button, code-behind, radiobuttonlist

Im creating radiobuttonlist accordingly. I want space in between them. All are done in code behind.

```
                RadioButtonList ddlst1 = new RadioButtonList();
                for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++)
                {

                    ddlst1.Items.Add(k.ToString());


                }                                  
                ddlst1.SelectedValue = i < choice1.Count() ? choice1[i] : string.Empty;
                ddlst1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
                ddlst1.AutoPostBack = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use cellpadding and cell spacing(But its at design time)

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ddlst1" runat="server" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
```

If you want to give at code behind 
then follow above answer
i.e..`ddlst1.Items[k].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-right:5px;")`

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt a css based approach

Looks like there is a solution here:

[How do I add space between items in an ASP.NET RadioButtonList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822122/how-do-i-add-space-between-items-in-an-asp-net-radiobuttonlist)

Inside your for loop:

```
ddlst1.Items[k].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-right:5px;")
```

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments i got this error. If take out Add it says identifier expected.